# Node or Python read keyboard keys when we terminal not focused

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-2.7, node-modules

i wanna create a execution macro with when my terminal not focused for example when i type "exit" > fire console.log("Fired") or python print("Fired");

i searched for 2 weeks everywhere and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a `keylogger`, I just typed `keylogger` in the searchbar at npm.com and I found a package which works fine on Mac and Linux.

Here is the package: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-keypress

If you want to see how it works internally, here is the source code:
https://github.com/miguelmota/global-keypress

I tried it, works fine on my linux computer and my mac.

Hope this helps